# Dynamically create Form from Fieldsets in Linhtining component Using <force:InputField> and <aura:repeat>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, fieldsets, aura-attribute

We are trying to create Fields loaded from Field-sets in a Lightning component Using Aura

This is what we Tried ;

## #

```
<aura:iteration items="{!$ObjectType.Lead.FieldSets.Partner_Registration_General}" var="f">
    <force:inputField value="{!f}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

## #

We tried the same thing Using Visualforce Page and wrap it in to the Lightining component .We used the Below code Snippet for it

```
         <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.FieldSets.Partner_Registration_General}"   var="f" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Lead[f]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
```

Can any one Guide us ,how we can acheive the same in Lightining Component . Any help would be valuable . Thanks in Advance ..